# Add delay between function calls inside a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a loop that iterates over an array.

I wanted to call a function with each element of the array being used as a parameter to it.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];

for (const a in arr) {
  console.log('immediately logging for ', a)
  setTimeout(() => {
    // wait for 5 seconds before doing next console logging
    function1(a)
  }, 5000);
}

var function1 = (a) => {
  console.log('after 5 seconds, logging for ', a)
}
```

To add the delay, I am using `setTimeout` between every two iterations.
;
However, exactly the opposite is happening

If we run this code, all the immediate logging console outputs are printed immediately.
After 5 seconds, all the logging happens together.

How do I perfectly add a delay for each iteration of `function1` and not call it in the loop instantly?

I may not have framed the question perfectly, please ask questions in the comments if anything is not clear :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use async/await:

```js
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            res();
        }, ms);
    });
}

async function main() {
    const arr = [1, 2, 3];
    for (const a of arr) {
        console.log(a);
        await sleep(1000);
    }
}

main();
```

Comment: I think it would be helpful to talk about why the code isn't working (the fact that `setTimeout` doesn't block the main thread)! :)

Comment: @ZameerAnsari Done

Answer (score 3):

One simple way is to scale the timeouts based on the array index.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
  console.log('immediately logging for ', arr[i])
  setTimeout(() => {
    // wait for 5 seconds before doing next console logging
    function1(arr[i])
  }, (i + 1) * 5000);
}

var function1 = (a) => {
  console.log('after 5 seconds, logging for ', a)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` doesn't work the way you might think it does. JavaScript has a stack (which the main thread operates on) and another data structure called the event queue. `setTimeout` does not block the main thread. It does not "pause" and wait for your callback in `setTimeout` to resolve itself. It throws the callback into the event queue and keeps running its computations.

Computers are fast, so it puts all of your callbacks into the event queue milliseconds between each other, which will cause every callback to be invoked within milliseconds of each other.

There are multiple strategies to have your code operate in the way you expect. The one that is easiest to reason about is manually blocking the main thread (halt all operations until the line of code is resolved).

As mentioned by others, this can be accomplished using a promise-based sleep function. The concept of promises is a completely different topic that can deeply dive into and out of the scope of your question. For the time being, just take my word for it when I say this: Using promises halts all subsequent operations until the promise is resolved. But make sure you're using the `await` keyword in front, or it will not block.

```js
const sleep = ms => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
async function intervalLog() {
  for (const a in arr) {
    console.log('immediately logging for ', a)
    await sleep(5_000) // 5 seconds. underscores for easier reading
  }
}

async function funcThatIntervalLogs() {
  await intervalLog() // you also have to await the async function that calls it in order for it to properly block the thread

// and then whatever operations you want afterward
}
```